# How would I get the linear combination of these coefficients for an ITS analysis?

Tags: regression, time-series, linear-model, regression-coefficients, segmented-regression

for a project I'm doing an interrupted time series analysis using a segmented linear regression. I'm trying to show that the trend (or slope) change after the first intervention (the first dotted line) was counteracted by the trend (or slope) change after the second intervention, i.e. that the trend/slope in the post-2nd intervention period returned to what it was before the 1st intervention. In picture form my data and model results look similar to this (these are just toy examples from a lecture I went to), except my two _trend variables are something like 7.43 for the first and -7.55 for the second interruption (The graph is just an example, not my actual data (I can't post it). In my actual data the post 2nd intervention slope looks very similar to the initial slope):

[image: https://imgur.com/cTUvloP]
[image: https://imgur.com/9YQB3pq]

Here's a toy example of how the data looks (ignore the red lines and green vs blue coloring). Basically, time is a sequential variable going from 1 to 72 (and tells you the slope/trend in the pre-1st intervention period), cerc is a 0,1 variable that is 0 until the record/month where the 1st interruption happens (this tells you the initial level shift up/down right after the 1st intervention, cerc_trend is 0 until the 1st intervention happens and then sequences from 1-42 (this tells you the slope changes from the pre vs post 1st interruption periods), and then cda and cda_trend are the same things except they start at the first month of the 2nd intervention and tell you respectively the level change right when the 2nd intervention happens (0 until it happens and 1 afterwards) as well as how the slope changes from the post 1st intervention period vs the post 2nd intervention period (0 until the 2nd intervention happens and then sequences from 1-16 after it does). I simply include all 4 of these variables + the time one in a gls( ) regression.

[image]

Can anyone suggest how I should go about this, particularly in R? I think I can get the linear combination of the two trend coefficients and that should give me what I need (I would also like confidence intervals for this)? How do I operationalize this as R code?
Thank you.

Comment: The third (final?) slope doesn't look at all like the first one to me. For one thing, it is negative, and the first one is positive.  So I don't see how you conclude that "the trend/slope in the post-2nd intervention period returned to what it was before the 1st intervention."

Comment: @jbowman Hi, the graph is just an example, not my actual data (I can't post it). In my actual data the post 2nd intervention slope looks very similar to the initial slope. The two trend coefficients I'm trying to compare respectively tell you how the slope changed in pre vs post 1st intervention period, and how the slope changed in the post 1st intervention period vs the post 2nd intervention period. I've now updated my post with a toy example of what my data looks like and explanation of how the indicators are coded.

Comment: @jbowman also I should add that the time coefficient/term tells us the slope/trend in the pre-1st intervention period

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by any of several appropriate restructurings of your independent variables.  I'll provide an example of a simple problem, one with just a target variable $y_t$ and a time trend $x_t$ with two breakpoints at $t = \delta_1$ and $t = \delta_2$.

One way to write the regression equation is to define two new variables, $x_t^{(1)}$ and $x_t^{(2)}$, to capture the changing trend.  $x_t^{(1)} = 0$ for $t < \delta_1$ and $= x_t-\delta_1+1$ for $t \geq \delta_1$, and similarly for $x_t^{(2)}$.

$$y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_t + \beta_2x_t^{(1)} + \beta_3x_t^{(2)} + e_t$$

In this formulation, the $x_t^{(j)}$ model the change in slope from what it was during the previous regime.

What we are interested in, however, is whether $\beta_3 = - \beta_2$.  Observe that if $\beta_3 = -\beta_2$, we don't need it at all, and we can rewrite the regression equation as:

$$y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_t + \beta_2(x_t^{(1)} -x_t^{(2)}) + e_t$$

Now we can add an extra term to estimate the deviation in the value of $\beta_3$ from $-\beta_2$:

$$y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_t + \beta_2(x_t^{(1)} -x_t^{(2)}) + \beta_3^*x_t^{(2)} + e_t$$

If $\beta_3 = -\beta_2$, $\beta_3^* = 0$, and vice versa.

This enables us to test the hypothesis that $\beta_3 = -\beta_2$ by testing, using whatever technique we prefer, the hypothesis that $\beta_3^* = 0$.

Some R code to set up an example:

```
# breakpoints at observations 20 and 40

x <- 1:60
x_1 <- c(rep(0,19), x[20:60]-19)
x_2 <- c(rep(0,39), x[40:60]-39)

beta_1 <- 0.5   # slope in period 1 = 0.5
beta_2 <- 1   # slope in period 2 = 1.5
beta_3 <- -1  # slope in period 3 = slope in period 1

y <- 1 + beta_1*x + beta_2*x_1 + beta_3*x_2 + rnorm(60)

plot(y~x)
```

with plot:

[image]

Estimation with the original variable set:

```
> summary(lm(y ~ x + x_1 + x_2))
    
*** stuff ***

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.25690    0.36299   3.463  0.00103 ** 
x            0.49094    0.02705  18.149  < 2e-16 ***
x_1          1.00755    0.04226  23.843  < 2e-16 ***
x_2         -0.99880    0.03775 -26.462  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

... and estimation with the redefined variable set:

```
> x_1_mod <- x_1 - x_2
> summary(lm(y ~ x + x_1_mod + x_2))

*** stuff ***

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.256904   0.362991   3.463  0.00103 ** 
x           0.490941   0.027050  18.149  < 2e-16 ***
x_1_mod     1.007545   0.042257  23.843  < 2e-16 ***
x_2         0.008745   0.031990   0.273  0.78559    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

We can see the coefficient estimates for the first two regimes are unchanged, but the coefficient estimate for the third regime is now not significantly different from zero.

If we change the value of the original $\beta_3$ from $-1$ to $-2$, so $\beta_3 \neq -\beta_2$, and rerun the final regression, we get:

```
> summary(lm(y ~ x + x_1_mod + x_2))

*** stuff ***

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.94447    0.41990   2.249   0.0284 *  
x            0.53039    0.03129  16.950   <2e-16 ***
x_1_mod      0.93686    0.04888  19.166   <2e-16 ***
x_2         -1.04732    0.03701 -28.301   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The first two coefficient estimates are not significantly different from their true values of $0.5$ and $1.0$ respectively, but the third coefficient estimate is now significantly different from $0$ and accurately estimates the change we made.